# Unable to list the account data in BigML

Tags: java, android, json, machine-learning, bigdata

My client gave me a BigML username and his api key. Following is my first attempt to list the stuff in account. Also please note this is my very first attempt with JSON as well.

```
package com.example.jsontest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

import java.net.URL;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.JsonReader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editText;
    private URL url;
    private Reader reader;
    private JsonReader jsonReader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        new getJSON().execute("");

        return true;
    }

    private class getJSON extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                url = new URL("https://bigml.io/andromeda/source?username=xxxx;api_key=xxxxxxxxx");
                reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
                jsonReader = new JsonReader(reader);

                jsonReader.beginObject();


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Error in Network", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            return "completed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            try
            {
                if(jsonReader==null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It is Null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It is Not Null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception io)
            {
                editText.setText("Error in IO: "+io.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        }

    }


}
```

But, the `JsonReader` is always null. What is happening here? The way I extracted data from `BigML` is wrong? any issue in JSON request?

Comment: show `JsonReader` class

Comment: @Raghunandan: It is a Android SDK class, not built by me